# How to lay divs horizontally without overflowing to new line?

Tags: html, css

I have a left floating div which serves as a sidebar (red). Next to it, there is another div that stores the page content (green). The elements inside the content div are left floating (blue).

I want to be able to scroll the boxes horizontally when the browser width is too small to accommodate them; for example if there are a lot of boxes. Instead, the content div moves below the sidebar div and I am scrolling the whole page.

Here is the page layout when the browser window is wide enough: 
[image: Page Layout]

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div id="content">
    <p class="box">Box 1</p>
    <p class="box">Box 2</p>
    <p class="box">Box 3</p>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#container {
    background: yellow;
}

#sidebar {
    float: left;
    background: red;
}

#content {
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: green;
}

.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    background: blue;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

Please help me understand what am I doing wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need something to wrap your content with the CSS property `overflow-x: scroll;`.

****Important**: This is a CSS3 feature and some browsers may not support `overflox-x`. Therefore, I highly suggest you read the following: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/html5-and-css3-without-guilt/.

**Preview**: http://jsfiddle.net/WXFJU/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="overflow-x">
      <div id="content">
        <p class="box">Box 1</p>
        <p class="box">Box 2</p>
        <p class="box">Box 3</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>​​​​​
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}

#sidebar {
    float: left;
    background: red;
}

#content {
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: green;
}

.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    background: blue;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.overflow-x {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display: block;
}
```

​

Comment: Thank you so much. Adding additional div with `overflow-x` property solves the problem!

Comment: That solution would be beyond awesome if `overflow-x` was CSS standard and not part of the CSS3 working draft; I guess we have to learn to settle with plain awesome. voteup++

Comment: @Hawken: Thanks for reminding me that this is a CSS3 feature! :P

Comment: Yeah, it's working great but IE9 is miles away from being able to comprehend this unfortunately :)

Comment: I am rather surprised that IE9 does not support this feature... :(

Comment: @apnerve: What version are you on?

Comment: Yeah, this is actually not so good solution after all. I changed `overflow-x` to plain `overflow` to try to make it a bit more compatible, but it appears that it only works in Chrome (haven't tried Safari though). It appears that the `white-space: nowrap;` in `#content` is ignored by other browsers. Any suggestions?

Comment: I got it! The `white-space: nowrap;` property is fine, but the `.box` class should have the `display: inline-block` property added and `float: left` removed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a width for the `container` too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, I am afraid that it does not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your content-div also needs to have a width.

```
#content {
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, I am afraid that it does not resolve the problem. Furthermore, the width of the content should be flexible.